# Has anyone ever seen this (*reinterpret_cast<void***>(r9))

Tags: c++, syntax, casting

Found this in some old C code.. , looking for an interpretation..
Has anyone ever seen this  `(*reinterpret_cast<void***>(r9))`

Comment: That's C++, not C.  It seems like a perfectly ordinary use of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @NateEldredge No, 3-star programming is not perfectly ordinary.

Comment: I took Nate's comment in the spirit of "any use of reinterpret_cast is bad; this bad case is typical of all the other bad cases... status quo badness."

Comment: What do you mean by "interpretation"? That snippet has a cast and an application of indirection, both reasonably common language constructs. What about it do you find confusing?

Comment: For those who aren’t familiar with the phrase [three-star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: Re: `Has anyone ever seen this?` Answer: yes. If you would like to ask a more refined question, please read [ask] and then [edit] your post at any time to clarify what you'd like to know.

Comment: This is a syntax correct expression. It cast r9 value to a void ***, which can be imaged as  a 3 dimension array r9. Then take a dereference to get the address of a 2 dimension array. The code is really bad, hard to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

The code is taking the value in `r9` and turning it into pointer to a memory location containing a `void**`.  It then loads the `void**` out of that memory location.

This is the moral equivalent of `*((int*)r9)`, just with different types.  Does that make sense?